# How does Flurry of Talons differ from Shadow Darts?

Tags: dnd-4e

Shadow Darts

> Attack: Dexterity vs. Reflex. Make three attack rolls. If any of them hit, resolve them as a single hit, and all of them must miss for the attack to miss.
>
> Hit: 1d8 cold damage if one of the attack rolls hits, 2d8 cold damage if two hit, **or** 3d8 cold damage if three hit.

Flurry of Talons

> Attack: Dexterity vs. Reflex. Make three attack rolls. If any of them hit, resolve them as a single hit, and all of them must miss for the attack to miss.
>
> Hit: 1d8 + Dexterity modifier damage if one of the attack rolls hits, 2d8 + Dexterity modifier damage if two hit, **and** 3d8 + Dexterity modifier damage if three hit.

Does the inclusion of an **and** in Flurry mean you do all of the listed damage if three attacks hit? As opposed to Shadow which uses **or** to show that you do one or the other.

Comment: Good question. This seems pretty unclear and possibly poor writing, but the former's level 1 and the latter's level 13...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Probably not.**

`6d8 + 3*Dex` is a *lot* of damage for a level 13 encounter power, even if it requires you to hit with 3 attack rolls. Given that Shadow Darts is at best a mediocre level 1 daily, (and most likely written by the same person, since they're from the same Dragon article), it's more likely that Flurry of Talons is a mediocre level 13 encounter power rather than an amazing one. Not to mention it's for the o-Assassin, which is apparently contractually obligated to suck.

While it's certainly poorly phrased, what's *probably* meant is something along the lines of:

> If 1 attack roll hits deal 1d8+Dex damage, deal 2d8+Dex damage if 2 attack rolls hit, and if 3 attack rolls hit deal 3d8+Dex damage.

The strength of powers that use multiple attack rolls for 1 hit is that they give you more chances for that hit to be a critical, not that they do great damage in and of themselves.

Comment: And resistances only come off the damage once, not 3 times.  But avoidance measures that can avoid one source of damage/one attack can avoid the whole lot.

Comment: It also gives you more chances to land at least some damage, if you've got a target who's already close to dropping, so you don't need to do much damage. When your target's HP is only 5, an 80% chance of dealing even thousands of damage isn't as good as a 90% chance of dealing 6.

Comment: Agreed, compare these powers to the other encounter powers of the same level introduced in that Dragon article. The other level 1 powers deal `2[W]+Dex` or `2d8+Dex` damage and include other effects so 1 to 3 d8 is a similar range. The level 13 encounter powers deal `2[W]+Dex`, `1d10+Dex`, and `2d6+Dex` again while granting other beneficial effects. A max of `3d8+Dex` gives this power higher max and average damage to offset it's lack of other effects while remaining comparable to your other choices at that level.